# How can I change ID of copied element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop

I try to create dnd editor with react-smooth-dnd. I have 2 containers: first is toolbar with elements, second is editor. 
Each elemnt have following structure:

```
{
 id: shortid.generate(),
 type: 'TextElement',
 options: {
    text: 'Text',
    style: {
       padding: '10px 0 10px 15px'
    },
    isShowToolBar: false
 }
}
```

When I try to copy element from first container to the second I want to change `id` of the current element, but when I try to do it with `onDrop` callback I can only change `id` of each elements of both containers.

***How can I change `id` only current element?***

My first (toolbar) container is:

```
<Container
  groupName="1"
  behaviour="copy"
  getChildPayload={i => this.state.items[i]}
>
  {
    this.state.items.map((element,i) => {
      const component = createComponent(element, TYPE_TOOLBAR);
      return (
        <Draggable
          key={i}
          style={{display: 'inline-block', padding: '10px'}}
          className="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-12"
       >
         {component}
       </Draggable>
      );
    })
  }
</Container>
```

And my second container (editor):

```
<Container
    groupName="1"
    getChildPayload={i => this.state.items[i]}
    onDrop={e => this.setState({
        items: applyDrag(this.state.items, e)
    })}
    lockAxis="y"
    dragHandleSelector=".element-drag-handler"
>
    {
        this.state.items.map((element, i) => {
            const component = createComponent(
                element,
                TYPE_EDITOR,
                this.elementToolBarHandler
            );

            return (
                <Draggable key={i}>
                    {component}
                </Draggable>
            );
        })
    }
</Container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking fof is reactCloneElement it allow you to take a component and changing his props.
Be carefull with this function it keep the refs from the element cloned.

Here my try on a possible implementation

```
const applyDrag = e => {

 const {items} = this.state
 // you get your element
 const element = e. ???? 

 // Then you recreate it and changing his id 
 const item = React.cloneElement(
  element,
  {
   id: shortid.generate(),
   ...element.props,
  },
)

 this.setState({items: items.length > 0 ? items.concat(item) : [].concat(item)})
}

<Container
    groupName="1"
    getChildPayload={i => this.state.items[i]}
    onDrop={this.applyDrag(e)}
    lockAxis="y"
    dragHandleSelector=".element-drag-handler"
>
    {
        this.state.items.map((element, i) => {
            const component = createComponent(
                element,
                TYPE_EDITOR,
                this.elementToolBarHandler
            );

            return (
                <Draggable key={i}>
                    {component}
                </Draggable>
            );
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried several ways and if you don't want clone element with `reactCloneElement` you can do following.

In my first container (toolbar) I've created a `onDragStart` callback:

```
onDragStart={e => this.onDragStart(e)}
```

Function implementation:

```
updateId(element) {
    let index = this.state.items.findIndex(x => x.id === element.id);
    if (index === -1) index = 1;
    this.setState(update(this.state, {
        items: {
            [index]: {
                $merge: {
                    id: shortid.generate()
                }
            }
        }
    }));
}

onDragStart({payload}) {
    this.updateId(payload);
}
```